# IPv4 to IPv6 UDP Holepunching

Tags: udp, ipv6, p2p, ipv4

So I'm writing a P2P multiplayer game. Server establishes connections (UDP) to each player and then gets the players to connect with each other directly (using the UDP Holepunching technique).

Then I tested at my parents house and wham - stopped working.

The reason is because my parents router is not IPv6 compatible.

**Question**

Is it possible to do UDP Holepunching between users that have different ip protocols?

**Aka**

- **User A:** 
  Behind router that has IPv4 address (can't send UDP messages to IPv6).
- **User B:**
  Has IPv6 address. Can send UDP messages to both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.

Or is this sort of setup doomed to fail?

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are completely separate, incompatible protocols. Hosts can run dual-stack (both IPv4 and IPv6), but IPv4 and IPv6 cannot directly communicate.

Comment: @RonMaupin - Right, I understand that. My cell phone seems to have both an IPv4 address and IPv6 address (as the server can accept connections from either protocol). But my Mac only has an IPv4 address under this router, and can't send UDP datagrams to IPv6 addresses.

Comment: "_my Mac only has an IPv4 address under this router, and can't send UDP datagrams to IPv6 addresses._" That would be correct. You would need something else (a kludge) that can translate, but IPv4-only devices cannot directly communicate with IPv6-only devices, and vice versa. We are near the end of 2018, and devices should be dual-stacked to use either protocol.

Comment: @RonMaupin - thanks for the feedback. The lack of information on IPv4/IPv6 UDP Holepunching on the internet is not a good sign. I've yet to find any good resources yet.

Comment: @RonMaupin - I've isolated the root of the problem. My cell phone (game client) has both an IPv6 and IPv4 address (supplied by the cell provider). When I send a udp packet to an IPv4 address, the cell provider acts as a router and gives me a port. However, unlike normal routers, it randomly changes the port anytime I send a udp packet to a different IPv4 address. I discovered this by running 2 servers and connecting to both of them, the IPv4 address is the same, but the port changes (even though my local udp port is the same for both messages). Need to slop together a work around now.

Comment: Good luck. And remember to ask your ISP to finish deploying IPv6. It's 2018 after all.

Comment: Yeah seriously would make all this stuff so much easier to implement. P2P is hard to get working when everyones service provider is juggling the available ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not directly possible to establish connections between IPv4 and IPv6.
If it isn't a realtime-based multiplayer game, there are some possible (gratuitously complex) workarounds.

1. User A could configure something like Teredo which effectively assigns an IPv6 address to his device.[1]
2. Both users could connect to a VPN where the server responsible for establishing connections is reachable via both protocols (dual-stack) or both users use IPv4 for connecting.
3. Both users could try to use NAT traversal on IPv4 (if user A needs to do that). As you have already experienced [and described in your third comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53291993/ipv4-to-ipv6-udp-holepunching#comment93467919_53291993) UDP hole punching (for user B, IPv4 CGNAT) is a mess.
4. User A could ask his ISP [to finish deploying IPv6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53291993/ipv4-to-ipv6-udp-holepunching#comment93482239_53291993).
5. User B could try to connect to user A via IPv4 if user A is able to open a port. Some CGNAT implementations then keep the connection for 30 seconds so you have to ensure that some sort of keep-alive datagrams get transmitted e.g. in an interval of 25 seconds.
6. User B could use a portmapper service. Use your favourite search engine: `portmapper ds-lite`. The service provides an IPv4 address where all connections to a specific port "connect through" to user B's IPv6 address (and a specific port).

[1] From personal experience I can tell you that some of the different available Teredo servers are unreliable. I had to try three different Teredo server configurations and actually need to switch between two of them because none of them is able to access all devices of the IPv6 internet - some devices can be reached via teredo.trex.fi, some of them via teredo.remlab.net - and then sometimes it just turns around.

In my opinion the least complex option would be 4.

If 5 doesn't work, I'd say that user A doesn't have Internet access but slightly enhanced web access only.

Comment: Some of my projects currently fail because of exactly the same problem. I even want to use hole-punching for TCP connections. I've switched my mobile ISP because the old one rejected 4. Now I have two fully working IPv4 internet connections and two IPv6+CGNAT IPv4 internet connections (residence 1, one of my friend's ISP, residence 2 and mobile).